# Set textbox value from image title but textbox and image are on different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set value of textbox from image title. Image and textbox are not on the same page both on different page . So there is any way to set textbox value as an title attribute of an image of different page using jquery ?

Comment: you will have to store it somehow.. using webstorage/cookies or via sending it to server as a request param... then read it in the second page and use it

Comment: You can use session(or cookies) or Querystring for that.. and using that onpageload u can set the page name

Answer (score 0):

QueryString would be the best way.
you can pass title of image in query string, fetch it from another page and set value of textbox as query string value;

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no problem even if they are on different pages.

Store the value in local storage and then fetch it for displaying on textbox on the another page.

local storage stores values in key-value pair.

Local Storage functions:
`window.localStorage.setItem("key",value);` to store the value in local storage.

`window.localStorage.getItem("key");` to fetch the value from local storage